# Route Authorities Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, security, routes

I have a route   `{path: 'Demands/:id', component: EditDemandesComponent},`
in this path I can edit my demand.
But if the id does not include in my demands id of an other user I can also access to this path and show their demands informations and edit.
How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Route Guards.

> A route guard is an important feature of the Angular Router that
> allows or denies the user access to the route pages based on some
> logic, based on weather user is logged in or not.
>
> - ROUTE-GUARDS are very much important in web app having login/logout scenarios.
> - It’s commonly used to check if a user is logged in and has the authorization to access a page.
> - We can easily manage which page is allowed for logged in user and which for non-logged in users.

Even tough you can do this on the Angular side, but I really suggest to do this on the Backend side. So once an unauthorized user is trying to get a demand, then it will return 401 and Angular will know that this user isn't authorized to do this.

Here are some good resources for the Angular Route Guards:

- https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/use-angular-route-guards-to-secure-angular-pages-by-allow-deny-or-redirect-to-other-page-view-f2537583e9a
- https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1

Comment: but this can just check if the user loggedIn or not (CanActivate)